# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError groovy compiler loading error

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am getting below error when I executing my JUnit test case. I am using Expectations plugin for Grails Domain Test case.

**BuildConfig.groovy file code:**

```
plugins {
   compile ":domain-expectations:0.6.1"
}
```

**Error which I am getting:**

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.lonecyprus.grails.test.Specification.<clinit>(Specification.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.createTest(TestSuite.java:63)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestMethod(TestSuite.java:310)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.addTestsFromTestCase(TestSuite.java:153)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.<init>(TestSuite.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.<init>(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:72)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit3Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit3Builder.java:11)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.10 and you are trying to load version 2.3.7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:509)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you have 2 versions of Groovy on classpath: 2.3.10 and 2.3.7. One is probably brought by Grails while the other is by the plugin, which means they are incompatible. You should try to exclude Groovy from the plugin dependency.

Comment: thanks, yes the reason is the same. We have to exclude Groovy from the plugin dependency. One another way of solving this problem I found here and it solved my problem http://blog.pdark.de/2014/12/08/groovy-lang-groovyruntimeexception-conflicting-module-versions-module-groovy-all-is-loaded-in-version-2-1-8-and-you-are-trying-to-load-version-2-1-9/

Answer (score 1):

maybe you had use groovy in two different denpendencies. For example : in  **com.jayway.restassured** and **io.rest-assured**, both of them include groovy-xml.

Comment: In my case, this is exactly what was happened. Thank you for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this 1st of you have chack the version of **groovy** in Maven Dependencies library and **Built path**. Version of **groovy** should be match so that this error will go else error will come because of version conflict.